# Rewriting a nasty looking Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone help me in simplifying this line i wrote? other than the ugly syntax, I'm certain there are other methods, other than eval to form a path

```
return send("link_to", "(#{order_string[:direction]})" 
         ,eval("#{controller}_path(#{query_string})"))
```

Guranteed that

```
controller               = contacts
query_string             = 'status: "ASC"'
order_string[:direction] = "ASC"
```

The above line should result in (and it does)

```
link_to "ASC",contacts_path(status: "ASC")
```

Comment: In which context this code have to work? Why you have to use `send` to call `link_to`?

Comment: It's a helper that provides sorting links, i am aware of a gem that does the same, but i prefer to keep my gem dependency to a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being inside a helper method you should be able to do:

```
return link_to(order_string[:direction], 
               send("#{controller}_path", query_string))
```

Given your parameters this is equivalent to:

```
return link_to('ASC', contacts_path(status: 'ASC'))
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using Eval, I would go with simplifying `link_to`, and not to use the routes method.

```
return link_to order_string[:direction],
               controller: controller, query_string
```

which it will translated to

```
return link_to 'ASC', controller: "contacts", status: 'ASC'
```

and in HTML

```
<a href="/contacts?status=ASC">ASC</a>
```

Also, beside controller, you can add `action` and `id` and Rails is smart enough to do the rest.

Comment: @amrnt I've tested your code and it didn't work, it's not syntactically valid in Ruby 1.9. It perhaps relies on Ruby 2's keywords arguments?

Comment: @toro2k it's almost valid (it's just trying to use 1.9 hash syntax) see the examples per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to; but you're right there's a small error

Comment: That's not valid Ruby in 1.9 or 1.8. You probably wanted to do `query_string.merge(controller: controller)`

Comment: @AaronK You got the point, since I can't test on Ruby 2.0 right now, can you confirm that it is valid Ruby 2.0 syntax?

Comment: @toro2k I don't think it is. The method definition _must_ be written using named parameters, otherwise, it's the normal Ruby sytnax (where last value may be an implicit hash). I don't know of Rails being re-written with the new named params; just yet.

Comment: Yeah! actually I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p0!